# Category equipped with a measure -- what is the name for this kind of object?

Tags: category-theory

I'm interested in studying the length of the shortest possible proof and proofs less than a fixed length in various simple logical systems. One way to organize this that seems fairly natural is a category equipped with a measure on its arrows. Is there a similar construction to this that actually exists?

I've tried looking up various combinations of "category" and "measure", but keep getting results for things like categories of measure spaces.

---

Let $L$ be the set of all well-formed formulas in a given langauge.

Now, create a category $\mathcal{C}$. In $\mathcal{C}$ the objects are $L$ and the arrows are proofs in a fixed deductive system where every line can be constructed by applying an inference rule to previous lines.

I will now define two "measures" $\mu_s$ and $\mu_l$ on the arrows of $\mathcal{C}$. Each measure can only take on values in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. $\mu_s$ measures a proof by counting the number of symbols in it. $\mu_l$ measures a proof by counting the number of lines, i.e. distinct statements, in a given proof.

Both of the measures satisfy the following rules:

$$ \mu(f) + \mu(g) = \mu(f \circ g) $$

$$ \mu(f) = 0 \iff \text{$f$ is an identity arrow} $$

However, $(C, \mu_s)$ is clearly a much stricter "accounting standard" for proof length than $(C, \mu_l)$ and they are different objects when thought of as "categories equipped with a metric".

This seems like a fairly natural structure.

It also lets me define a "directed distance metric between objects" that's *very loosely analogous to the [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)* between probability distributions. Let $\wedge$ be the minimum or greatest lower bound, as appropriate.

$$ \text{the directed distance from $A$ to $B$} = \bigwedge_{f \in \mathrm{Hom}(A, B)} \mu(f) $$

Comment: I didn't see this question when I was searching initially, but my question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570512/whats-the-real-name-for-these-things-categories-whose-morphisms-have-length). However, the other question doesn't have any answers yet, isn't approaching the question from the perspective of logic, and doesn't explicitly consider the possibility of different distances from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: Are $\mu_s$ and $\mu_l$ functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to the monoid $(\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0},+)$ regarded as a single object category?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Hmm. Yes. I think that works. You can assemble the distances into the arrows of a category with a single object. And if your set of distances is $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{\ge_0}$, you can express $\ge$ on distances as well.

Comment: A category with a "metric" satisfying the laws you postulate is a rather strange one. For example, it cannot have any non-trivial isomorphisms. Actually, any split monomorphism or split epimorphism would itself have to be an identity morphism. It is unclear to me whether such a category is worth studying _qua_ category (as opposed to say, a graph).

Comment: Eliminating the $\mu(f) = 0$ axiom is okay I suppose, in the motivating use case I'm proposing it just corresponds to a proof with no content ... so maybe a system where doing something like unfolding definitions or using the associativity of $\land$ or something is free.

Comment: So, according to Geoffrey's comment, can we say that what you're looking for are precisely the categories equipped with a functor to $(\Bbb Z_{\ge 0},+)$?

Comment: @Berci Yes. I was hoping Geoffrey would promote that comment to an answer, but I suppose anyone could do it.